# Cannot run Swing programs on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, swing, ubuntu

I have to do a GUI project for a class, and I cannot run the program I'm writing. I have looked everywhere so I tried to run the simplest program:

```
package start; 
/*
* HelloWorldSwing.java requires no other files. 
*/
  import javax.swing.*;        

  public class HelloWorldSwing {
  /**
  * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
  * this method should be invoked from the
  * event-dispatching thread.
  */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("HelloWorldSwing");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Add the ubiquitous "Hello World" label.
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello World");
    frame.getContentPane().add(label);

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
    }
}
```

I have the java compiler, I know because when I use java -version on my terminal it returns this:

```
openjdk version "9-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195526.buildd.src)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195526.buildd.src, mixed mode)
```

I also have the JRE.

When I compile it, I use `javac start/HelloWorldSwing.java` (It does compile)
But when i try to run it with `java start.HelloWorldSwing` it returns this:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xb6aafe48, pid=4166, tid=4180
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (9.0) (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195526.buildd.src)
# Java VM: OpenJDK Client VM (9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195526.buildd.src, mixed mode, serial gc, linux-x86)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libjava.so+0x18e48]  JNU_GetEnv+0x18
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %P" (or dumping to /home/carcamo/Escritorio/myhw/core.4166)
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/carcamo/Escritorio/myhw/hs_err_pid4166.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

I would really appreciate any help I can get on this issue

Comment: That doesn't look like a bug coming from the Java program itself but rather from the JVM. If you haven't yet done so, perhaps it's time to re-install Java on that machine as it may be corrupted.

Comment: Program works fine in Oracle binary in the latest version of 9 ea b143 (https://jdk9.java.net/download/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a version of Java that is a supported release?  Try openjdk 8, or download the Oracle Java 8 release (currently 8u102).